# How can I get at a code file attachment in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, attachment

This might be something for [superuser](http://superuser.com), but it's a programmer's problem.

If you send a .vb, .cs, .js, or anything else that Outlook thinks is code it blocks it.

Not in the way that it does with images where it warns you and lets you override it - it absolutely blocks it.

Thing is, as a developer I might want to be able to send and receive code files. I might even know how to read them without executing them :-/

There's lots of ways round this for the sender - rename the file, zip it up, use personal mail, etc (all of which should be unnecessary, but never mind).

But if someone's sent me a file, and forgotten to change it to spoof the dumb and trivial security in Outlook, is there any way that I can override Outlook's behaviour and access the file?

I realise that this is something an Exchange admin can do, but let's assume that role is done in such a way that any change will take years and cost many trees of paperwork.

I think the attachment is still buried in the mail - so any way I can get at it?

Comment: +1: "I realise that this is something an Exchange admin can do, but let's assume that role is done in such a way that any change will take years and cost many trees of paperwork."

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Comment: 2007, but it's done it since 2000 I think

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a nasty trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/nicold/archive/2008/03/25/howto-unblock-restricted-file-attachments-in-microsoft-outlook-2007.aspx) (but I haven't verified it).